# Pandas Merge (subtract) Two Rows with same absolute value

Tags: python, pandas

```
              Quantity  frequency
0                  200        158
1                 -200        116
2                  500         85
3                 1000         62
4                  300         57
5                 -500         51
6                 -300         50
```

I am trying to subtract two frequencies having the same `abs(Quantity)` and updating `column['frequency']`
and order by frequency.

Output:

```
              Quantity  frequency
0                 1000         62
1                  200         42
2                  500         34
3                  300          7
...
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ONe way of doing it.

```
a = abs(df.Quantity)
b = df[df.groupby(a)["frequency"].transform('count')>1]
c = df[df.groupby(a)["frequency"].transform('count')==1]
d = b.groupby(a)['frequency'].apply(lambda x: x.values[0]-x.values[-1]).reset_index()
d.append(c)
```

**Output**

```
Quantity    frequency
0   200     42
1   300     7
2   500     34
3   1000    62
```

Answer (score 1):

This will yield the results you seek:

```
query = df.copy()
query["abs_quantity"] = query["Quantity"].abs()
abs_freq = pd.DataFrame(data=query.abs_quantity.value_counts()) \
             .reset_index(level=0) \
             .rename(columns={"index": "abs_quantity",
                              "abs_quantity": "abs_freq"})
results = query.merge(abs_freq, on="abs_quantity") \
               .query("abs_freq == 1")[["Quantity", "frequency"]] \
               .sort_values(by="frequency", ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code snippet:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
if int(row["Quantity"])<0:
    # Make all quantities as positive
    row["Quantity"]=row["Quantity"]*-1
    # Transfer the quantity sign to freq
    row["Freq"]=row["Freq"]*-1
```

This will change the sign.

```
df.groupby(['Quantity']).sum()
```

This will group it by the quantity.